# Convert Resultset to CSV file using Java

Tags: java, csv, resultset

Hi I am trying to convert oracle jdbc resultset to csv file. Below is the code used. Issue occures when there is value like below in the field. It deforms the output csv and all this come in separate line rather than in one field.

Value in Field comes in csv as

> [<333message:Runtime error in script' ProcessItem: ' Type: 'ITEM'" 1:0).Internal Script     error: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       Script (line 1):
>         **setHours = 0 ;**
>       if(ts.instanceId == null)
>       "   3 :     ts.instanceId = 0 ;"
>       Step >]

```
int ncols = result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();  

            System.out.println("ColumnCout"+ncols);  
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.csv"),false);  
            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(fos),"UTF_8");      

            for (int j=1; j<(ncols+1); j++) {     
            out.append(result.getMetaData().getColumnName (j));       
            if (j<ncols) out.append(","); else out.append("\r\n");      
            }   
            int m =1;    

            while (result.next()) {   

            for (int k=1; k<(ncols+1); k++) {   

            out.append(result.getString(k));    

            if (k<ncols) out.append(","); else out.append("\r\n");    
            }   
            //System.out.println("No of rows"+m);   
            m++;   
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value for the column that could have *new lines* as

```
String multiLine = null;
if (k == <col_index> && (mutiLine = rs.getString(k)) != null)
    out.append(multiLine.replaceAll("\\n", ""));
else
    out.append(result.getString(k));
```

You could filter all the columns as well but then would incur some performance hit.

Comment: Though it took care of new line but it did not complete. While writing 1439 rows it quit in 3 rd col.

Comment: last 4 lines of csv
92471 147183  Msg for 10641508 Processed Determine Next Activity From Host Msg null 2/20/2013 13:17
92472 147184  Msg for 10641505 Processed Determine Next Activity From Host Msg null 2/20/2013 13:17
92468 147185  Msg for 10641504 Processed Determine Next Activity From Host Msg null 2/20/2013 13:17
92470 147181  Msg for 10641506 Processed Determine Next Activit

Comment: I'm unable to understand due to not being familiar with your data. Could you compare this with your previous CSV and point out the issue? Feel free to update your question with the info.

Comment: Yes I compared and the previous also didnt complete. I am still trying to understand why it didnt complete. Thank you Ravi

Answer (score 23):

Are you using "java.sql.ResultSet" class?
If yes, see the library in this link http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

See an example:

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
java.sql.ResultSet myResultSet = .... ;
csvWriter.writeAll(myResultSet, includeHeaders);
```

Comment: Yes I am using java.swl.Resultset. Due to some constraint opencsv is not allowed to use.